# Getting value and index of array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array in Matlab, let say of (256, 256). Now i need to build a new array of dimensions (3, 256*256) containing in each row the value, and the index of the value in the original array. I.e:

```
test = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]

test =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

I need as result:

```
[1, 1, 1; 2, 1, 2; 3, 1, 3; 4, 2, 1; 5, 2, 2; and so on]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the output of `meshgrid`

```
[C,B]=meshgrid(1:size(test,1),1:size(test,2))
M=test;
M(:,:,2)=B;
M(:,:,3)=C;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new at matlab and I think I messed up with the question. Let me rephrase, I have an image in a matrix of 256x256 and need to get a "list" of the images coordinates along with the value in the coordinate. So, if position 1,1 of the matrix contains the value 145, then first row of the resulting array will be [145, 1, 1] and so on.

Answer (score 1):

here's what i came up with

```
test = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]; % orig matrix

[m, n] = size(test); % example 1, breaks with value zero elems
o = find(test);
test1 = [o, reshape(test, m*n, 1), o]
```

Elapsed time is 0.004104 seconds.

```
% one liner from above
% (depending on data size might want to avoid dual find calls)
test2=[ find(test) reshape(test, size(test,1)*size(test,2), 1 ) find(test)]
```

Elapsed time is 0.008121 seconds.

```
[r, c, v] = find(test); % just another way to write above, still breaks on zeros
test3 = [r, v, c]
```

Elapsed time is 0.009516 seconds.

```
[i, j] =ind2sub([m n],[1:m*n]); % use ind2sub to build tables of indicies
                                % and reshape to build col vector
test4 = [i', reshape(test, m*n, 1), j']
```

Elapsed time is 0.011579 seconds.

```
test0 = [1,2,3;0,5,6;0,8,9]; % testing find with zeros.....breaks
% test5=[ find(test0) reshape(test0, size(test0,1)*size(test0,2), 1 ) find(test0)] % error in horzcat

[i, j] =ind2sub([m n],[1:m*n]); % testing ind2sub with zeros.... winner
test6 = [i', reshape(test0, m*n, 1), j']
```

Elapsed time is 0.014166 seconds.

Using meshgrid from above:
Elapsed time is 0.048007 seconds.

Comment: So, if you dont have zeros, I'd recommend using find. Otherwise ind2sub? Keep in mind this for a realllly small dataset. You should `tic toc` to find out how it scales with your data.